# Как сделать что-бы камера на растягивала изображение по X, при этом он должен увеличиваться по Y и чтобы X увеличивался в зависимости от Y

Tags: java, libgdx

Вот код:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    FrameBuffer fbo;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    OrthographicCamera cam;
    Main m;
    Res res;
    Sprite frame;
    GameRenderer gRend;
    int heght;
    int wight;

    public GameScreen(Main m){
        this.m = m;
    }



    @Override
    public void show() {

        wight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        heght = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB888,7*16*8,5*16*8,false);
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(7*16*8,5*16*8);
        res= new Res();
        gRend = new GameRenderer();
        res.sprL();
        cam.position.set(new Vector3(7*16*8/2,5*16*8/2,0));

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        fbo.begin();
            gRend.renderMenu(batch,res);
        fbo.end();

        frame = new Sprite(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
        frame.flip(false,true);

        cam.update();
        
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        batch.begin();

            frame.draw(batch);

        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

        batch.dispose();
        fbo.dispose();

    }
}
'''
```

Comment: То есть чтобы камера масштабировалось в зависимости от Y

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то надо копать в сторону Viewports. http://www.libgdx.ru/2014/08/viewports.html